# Not sure what forum(s) to ask: Getting payment from Amazon affiliate links

Tags: discussion

Site recommendation request:

I have a website, now at (redacted), formerly at (redacted) (PR4, redirects to the new location).

There are a mixture of Powell's and Amazon affiliate links on that website: Powell's if I find Powell's has a copy of the item in stock when I create the link, or Amazon otherwise.

The reason I have been using Powell's primarily is a proto-hacker's comments about Powell's being an exception to a rule about affiliate programs being run by scumbags ((redacted)).

I have received repeated checks from Powell's, albeit not recently: this may or may not be related to the fact that when I check for title availability on Powell's it is increasingly likely not to be available.

I have never received affiliate payment from Amazon, and I believe I have been credited with 1-2 affiliate sales in over a decade of affiliate use.

What, if any, options do I have available to get paid?

Comment: Don't they have a minimum payout? Not going to send you a check for $4.

Comment: Have to ask: is this personal finance, or (admittedly small) business?

Comment: (Admittedly small) business, @keshlam. I posted on Meta because I wasn't sure.